# How to differentiate if python script is running on putty ssh or on VNC's terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way to differentiate between following 2 ways of running a python script?

1. Connecting to virtual machine with putty ssh and running a python
   script on it
2. Logging into virtual machine using VNC Viewer and
   running python script directly on its terminal

I need a way to figure out from these 2 options which way the script is running and take an action accordingly. If is it running through ssh, I need to open webbrowser on remote machine, otherwise on VNC machine itself. Can someone give a suggestion here if it is doable?

Comment: For most cases I can think of, the usual solution would be to go through your open windows and see which one the script is in.

Comment: on linux you could check the value of the environment variable $DISPLAY

Comment: In script itself I need to give a provision based on the platform on which it is running.

Comment: `$DISPLAY` is `null` on putty ssh window and on VNC it shows `:3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you're running in a GUI environment (X11), then the DISPLAY variable is set.  Example code to access the `DISPLAY` environment variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> print( 'DISPLAY' in os.environ )
```

Another option exploits the fact that OpenSSH will usually set a couple of variables (configuration willing):

```
>>> print( 'SSH_CONNECTION' in os.environ )
>>> print( 'SSH_CLIENT' in os.environ )
>>> print( 'SSH_TTY' in os.environ )
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct that for `VNC` it will set `DISPLAY` to some number and it will give `KeyError: 'DISPLAY'` for putty ssh?

Comment: My understanding is that connecting by VNC requires a display, therefore the `DISPLAY` variable will exist. I'm not sure it's exactly proper to say that *VNC sets the variable*. @npatel -- But in effect yes.

Comment: @npatel I might use `.has_key()` as a more robust check for existence over handling an exception after attempting access, but yes, the concept is that those variables will exist (or not) depending upon the parent environment.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated, and gone in Python 3. Use `in`.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point; I normally would do so.  Not sure why I didn't there.  Thanks!